# Value of a zero sum game

Tags: game-theory

I've been looking some around on the net for some info on zero-sum games,
But I don't think I fully understand the principle;
If we consider the (simple) matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}\pi&0 \\ 0&e \end{pmatrix}$$

How can I determine the value of this zero-sum game?

Is this the possible correct answer regarding this example?

Let us just call first row R1, first column C1 and so on.

Then, the expectation for R1 is $\pi \cdot p_1$.
Then, the expectation for R2 is $e \cdot p_2$.

Now I have to maximize: $min(E(R1),E(R2))$, which implies $p_1=e:p_2=\pi$.

So we see $p_1=0.464$ and $p_2=0.536$

We can do the same for C1,C2, which will give the same numbers.

Therefore I think the value of this game is $0.464 \cdot \pi=1.457= 0.536 \cdot e$

Is this ok?
Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will denote the mixed strategies of the first player by $(p, 1- p)$ and of the second player by $(q, 1 - q)$ and the payoff function determined by your matrix by $g$.
For the first player, we have to calculate
$$ V = \max_{0 \leq p \leq 1} \min_{0 \leq q \leq 1} g((p,1-p),(q,1-q)) = \max_{0 \leq p \leq 1} \min_{q \in \{0,1\}} g((p,1-p),(q,1-q)). $$
That is,
$$ V = \max_{0 \leq p \leq 1} \min \{ p\pi, (1-p)e \}. $$
Plotting it, we have

[image]

So we see that the max-min is attained only at the intersection of $p\pi$ and $(1-p)e$, that is, when $p = \frac{e}{\pi + e} \approx 0.464$ and the value of the game is the payment at $(p,1-p)$ so $V = \frac{\pi e}{\pi + e} \approx 1.457$.

Comment: Yeah this is a much better way to denote the answer :) ty for your time!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @levap: You've got an error in the equation: $\max \min=\min \max$, instead of $\max \min = \max \min$.

Comment: @amorfati: There is no error. I've only calculated $\max \min$. It is equal to $\min \max$ but there is no need to treat it since this is guaranteed...

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood what you actually did. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I have a doubt. For two player zero sum game if security level of player 1 is s1 and player 2 is s2, does that mean s1+s2 = 0?  Or s1=s2? Your answer is making me think that

Comment: If by security level for both players you mean $s_1 = \max_{x \in \Delta_m} \min_{y \in \Delta_n} u_1(x,y)$ and $s_2 = \max_{y \in \Delta_m} \min_{x \in \Delta_n} u_2(x,y)$ (where $u_i(x,y)$ is the expected payoff to player $i$ where player $1$ plays the mixed strategy $x$ and player $2$ plays the mixed strategy $y$ and $u_2 = -u_1$) then yes, $s_1 = -s_2$. This is the content of the famous minmax theorem.