# Two person zero sum problem, help/guidance needed..

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, game-theory

I'm a computer science student and I have this problem I need to solve for my games theory course. I don't have an example to follow, or use as guidance, and my colleagues are not very helpful( as in, they have no interest in solving this).

I managed to solve a non constant sum problem, as I had an example for that one. But I can't wrap my head around this one.

So, here's the problem:

---

Consider a finite two person zero-sum game with a payoff matrix A which is a matrix of order 7. Further assume that the row sums and column sums are all equal to 28. Then find the value of the game and a pair of optimal strategies for the two players.}

---

Some help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Maybe a solved problem(not necessarily this one), that I can use as an example would be even better, but I don't want to ask too much

Thanks

Comment: see this for a bit on calculating the value: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239803/value-of-a-zero-sum-game.  then you need to see what restrictions the row and column sums put on the matrix.  I'm guessing that's the tricky part.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy profile in which both players uniformly randomly choose among the $7$ strategies is a Nash equilibrium. Since all row sums and all column sums are equal, neither player can change the expected payoff by switching strategies.